# Migrating users from .com to .org?

Tags: users, migration, password

I am in the process of migrating my blog from my [wordpress.com address](https://dekhoblog.wordpress.com/) to a self-hosting (wordpress v3.1.2) [address](http://www.dekho.com.au/).

Blog has migrated across nicely.

Appears my users have also migrated across, but they cannot login with there old credentials (which are tied to wordpress.com, right)?

I have around 30 users, and I would like to minimise the amoutn of work they have to do, to re-register to get access to the wp-admin console.

What is the best way to keep the new users, but perhaps reset all there password to 'password'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you can see the email addresss of your users in wordpress.com blog as i never used it. If you can, as you have not too many users you may try to add them manually from wordpress dashboard and send them an email with the password if you have access to the email address.

Comment: I know all the email addresses, as they are all internal staff with same domain for email.  But was hoping that I would not have to manually enter all their emails and new passwords.  Anyway to bulk apply this without fear of messing things up?

Comment: You've already messed it up by the sounds of things :) Password-reminders are pretty harmless.

Comment: Not sure im with you.  If the wordpress.com passwords did not port across, then im simply looking for a way to batch change everyones password (cos the users ported across) to something that they can login with and then change there passwords to something unique.

Comment: @Simon: yes. You can create some random password then users can change it when they logged in. I think manually doing 30 users is not a lot work. If you had lots of users that case you can create some wordpress code to make it automated. Also i am not sure if there is any plugin to do that.

Comment: I did thttp://svw-bne-support/Rep/incident/default.aspx?ID=37992Just manually added everyones emails and a default password.  Was not the anwer I was looking for, but thanks.